# Passing dynamic data to Highcharts series data element

Tags: javascript, c#, highcharts, datatable

I am currently trying to pass data from my back-end (written in c#) to my front-end to be used within the JavaScript to populate a highcharts x-range graph. The data comes through and is filtered as and when needed correctly but passing the data to the highcharts series data element is proving difficult. When giving the element the raw data copied from the source, it works fine, however when passing the data dynamically it does not, for example:

```
series: [{
  pointWidth: 20,
  turboThreshold: 10000,
  data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("[" + dataString + "]"))
}]
```

the above is what I am tring to do, the dataString is comprised as follows:

```
dataString += "{x: " + startDate + ", x2: " + endDate + ", y: " + vesselCounter + "},"
```

where each variable is passed through from a row in the datatable in the back-end. Running the code like this returns an empty chart, however if I run it as follows

```
series: [{
  pointWidth: 20,
  turboThreshold: 10000,
  data: [{x: 1244419200000, x2: 1258329600000, y:0}]
}]
```

the data displays, I'm not sure if it's not possible to pass the data as I am trying but any help would be great! To clarify the data comes through perfectly and is as it should be but the series -> data element does not like it.

Docs for reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xrange.data

Comment: Hi @lewis337, I don't think that you need to use `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`, it seems to be doing things a bit around. Could you add a sample of your data returned from backend to the question?

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Unfortunately I can't show the data is it is quite sensitive, however after removing the json parse and stringify the outputted data is the same as before and the graph still shows blank.

Comment: I mean that you should use a different approach, only removing the function will not help. You can use some mocked data, but I assume that you have something like: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lcuzex2j/ and you can simply build the required format in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mk8u2shd/

Comment: @lewis337 you can see running code.

Comment: @ppotaczek, with the code you provided in the second link, the data is hard coded which works fine but I have to pass the data from the backend dynamically as it constantly changes which is where the issues is, if that makes sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by passing the series data as an object

```
function dateObject(_x, _x2, _y) {
  this.x = _x
  this.x2 = _x2
  this.y = _y
}
```

thank you everyone for helping and if anyone has questions on this feel free to ask :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).